# TypeScript generic fetch function, wrong type for BodyInit

Tags: typescript, node-fetch

I don't understand this error. It says `toBody()` returns a `Blob` type. but to me it should return a string which is accepted by `BodyInit`

`type BodyInit = Blob | BufferSource | FormData | URLSearchParams | ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | string;`

```
export class CredentialsRequestBody
  implements RequestBody<CredentialsRequestBody> {
  constructor(username: string, password: string) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }
  username: string;
  password: string;
  toBody(): BodyInit {
    console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, this)).toString());
    return '{"username":"jonas", "password": "something"}'; //JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, this)).toString();
  }
```

```
type methods = 'DELETE' | 'POST' | 'GET' | 'POST';
export async function request(
  url: string,
  method: methods,
  headers: any,
  body: RequestBody<any>
): Promise<any> {
  const defaultHeaders = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };

  const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
    method: method !== null ? method : 'GET',
    headers:
      headers !== null
        ? {
            ...defaultHeaders,
            ...headers
          }
        : defaultHeaders
  };
  if (
    body !== null &&
    requestOptions.method !== 'GET' &&
    requestOptions.method !== 'DELETE'
  ) {
    requestOptions.body = body.toBody();
  }

  const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);//<--requestOptions INVALID
  return response.json();
}
```

```
fetch/index").RequestInit'.
  Types of property 'body' are incompatible.
    Type 'BodyInit' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/jonas/WebstormProjects/mindtherags-backend/node_modules/@types/node-fetch/index").BodyInit'.
      Type 'Blob' is not assignable to type 'BodyInit'.
        Type 'Blob' is missing the following properties from type 'ArrayBuffer': byteLength, [Symbol.toStringTag]

29   const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[9:40:22 PM] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.
```

even converting a string to a `Blob` and passing it directly as `RequestInit.body` yields the same error. Could the type be off?

```
  const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
    method: method !== null ? method : 'GET',
    headers:
      headers !== null
        ? {
            ...defaultHeaders,
            ...headers
          }
        : defaultHeaders,
    body: new Blob([JSON.stringify({ something: 'something' })], {
      type: 'text/plain'
    })
  };
  /*if (
    body !== null &&
    requestOptions.method !== 'GET' &&
    requestOptions.method !== 'DELETE'
  ) {
    requestOptions.body = JSON.stringify({ something: 'something' });
  }*/

  const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
  return response.json();
}
```

```
Argument of type 'RequestInit' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/home/jonas/WebstormProjects/mindtherags-backend/node_modules/@types/node-fetch/index").RequestInit'.
  Types of property 'body' are incompatible.
    Type 'BodyInit' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/jonas/WebstormProjects/mindtherags-backend/node_modules/@types/node-fetch/index").BodyInit'.
      Type 'Blob' is not assignable to type 'BodyInit'.
        Type 'Blob' is missing the following properties from type 'ArrayBuffer': byteLength, [Symbol.toStringTag]ts(2345)
```

```
    body: JSON.stringify({
      something: 'something'
    })
```

does not work either

uninstalling `@types/node-fetch` and fetching through anyways with `Blob`, `JSON.stringify(obj)` and `toBody()` as the body all yield the following error on the request

```
(node:145700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Request internals)' of null
```

which is this function `node-fetch`

```js
const INTERNALS$2 = Symbol('Request internals');

/**
* Check if a value is an instance of Request.
*
* @param   Mixed   input
* @return  Boolean
*/
function isRequest(input) {
   return typeof input === 'object' && typeof input[INTERNALS$2] === 'object';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the typescript issue has to do with conflicting definitions is different places, since the error is specifically saying that your `BodyInit` type is not assignable to the one from the `@types/node-fetch` folder.

`RequestInit` has a definition in `lib.dom.d.ts` which differs slightly from the one in the node-fetch package.  For example dom allows `BodyInit` to be `null` but node-fecth doesn't.

For the record, I'm not seeing any error in the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAIQPYBMIEkB2BLMcC8iANkgEZwA%20iArgGa0wBOAyktYwMbxUBiSjAWwAiAQzAjKcAKoAlADLMYIzgAsACspECAzpJlKUI0kRjMwjJQIA8U7JjAAOAIKNGIiAD5J283YDmANygoAD0IZCwiKgYOHiEAHJImPHURERGJlZw%20gCO1DA%20WLgA2gDkpNGlALpwHgFwwSB2YEy0IlzZMHkFYMhoVgAqXgDeoHBwYEh9EAAUAJQAXFFoRWBBIAC%20jTAAHlD8eBzp2roAwhYoMPbYIkTaufk%2002Nw2AJQJgJXYLoPPdNWc4wS7XW73LqPXrREYvDhJHyMagcSaMGbUbRMTBaGBLBH%20AA0cCgIhOAHd%20Chcb5MH45nBRiBxuMwCpsNoAHTozHYghwLmMLFfdZMiasjnEskU3kS7TkxgoYVwLaMvkYgXYqmMfyKmVyylwPE0xWTabzJbTVb0l7jOGYbRIEzskh%20GYRGBIWhwABSzAA8vF2Ya-NhaLNfaQAFYwZHsknabB%20TAzYYbQkstlzObsyZmLU0%20ZzRXjCxgdiYOClYYAIn5gpgVYWVYjSRJVcJVd1FIbcCr9q%206ZpVY2pXqYR9-sD1ODoZm4ajMbjCaTKbTYsz2aQuf880VyvGypebrg-ZUqF0hFKQgAonIrwMr6VJKU1L7mANH1RSgBxO8fisvt8R1AXZ9kYPASQgTAODgWhqCgsBsCSOALG6HwZhedgiE1AkXhPVAljwlBtHxF4VAMJhtCWERMAgEiVQqNAlj%20J5oisajPFARY4DURgkAENkYDYmiYRVW0fDgS42lSMAAAlyMYc8rRVcZSlOJIWnsABaAZoBgUollKEQoA%20bAODERDMBCCN7UwUoXg2dZYXhPAUMhX0oAQ%20EmIhHpLUIBkRUIgiYBZVA4AAQnwQhMFSIg4AAfmPELTxQOADJ-d86JFMiREuBSFmtJkcry3RIui2LCpFRKApFWrxnZBrJJEaS5Nyiisrq2qGvZYqKMq2q906pYmpa%20TtHsxUQzgdDlLgBiIAiqK4BitI4AAMjWwrXJ6dzPLtdlCMWi8MsfDatp8nxdosjlDrKitr1ve87JVOkauLC6wCu%20F2Xm3l5o3U1C3sxobWc5CCn2O14EIERSREXAYJCjgVDRRgiEJbbLo867CzCKxNM0zHPux%20E4HQeIADUnDkdAhBeEsy3B7RIYxdlrKSHdQA2IA), but I think that's using the `lib.dom` definition for the fetch function.